# JAVA_HOME not found as Sudo

Tags: java, linux, sudo, java-home

I have a bash script on a Linux box that runs a Jar file. When logged in as a regular user I don't have permission to run the script, but it prints the following log:

```
*INFO * Using JVM found at /opt/jdk6/bin/java
```

When I try to use the script with Sudo though, it gives:

```
*ERROR* Unable to locate java, please make sure java is installed and JAVA_HOME set
```

I've set `JAVA_HOME` to the same path above — can see it with `echo $JAVA_HOME` & it's also set as an option within the script. I'm happy that the script isn't the issue — it's a default CQ5 control script & I'm using it on dozens of other boxes without issue. Just unsure what I'm doing wrong above & presume it's something I'm missing re Linux set-up?

When I run the `sudo` command, does it have access to the `JAVA_HOME` that I set up as myself?

Comment: What is the exact output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` both as root and as regular user?

Comment: Andrew, I don't have access as the root user itself on the machine (not the sysadmin), just as a sudoer. Just found the issue over here though: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/java-home-not-set-in-script-when-run-using-sudo Sudo was stripping the environment variable, managed it with the `sudo -E` flag

Comment: I believe it depends on the distro - some sudos keep envs, others don't

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By default, `sudo` will cleanup the environment of the spawned commands. Pass `-E` to keep it:

```
sudo -E env
```

Compare to:

```
sudo env
```

Comment: Thanks mate, just found it on unix.stackexchange at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

"sudo -E " didn't solve the problem when JAVA_HOME was not exported. And when it was exported, "sudo " without -E works the same.

So you can add `export JAVA_HOME=.../jdk<version>` in your .bash_profile and .bashrc file.

In case you wondered what's the difference of .bash_profile and .bashrc, .bash_profile is executed upon login (e.g., show some diagnostic/welcome information). .bash_rc is executed when you open a new terminal (e.g., shift-ctrl-T).

In order to run some commands for both cases, you can put it in .bashrc file, and let .bash_profile source .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always just pass it to java explicitly like this:

`sudo java -Djava.home=$JAVA_HOME Test`

Comment: I see inception.. :D (Although the downvote is not from me.. )